How can we model the primordial Universe while the interior of a neutron star and comparable states of matter are still mostly unknown?
There is something I never quite understood about the physics of the primordial Universe. There are states of matter at high temperature/high pressure that are still, today, poorly understood. The firsts that come to my mind are neutron star or hypothetical strange quark star. But even the exact mechanisms at the core of the sun, or at the core of some planets seem to lack a full understanding. To that we can also add hypotheses in nuclear physics such as the island of stability and the continent of stability.
With of all that taken into account, and given the extreme conditions of temperature and pressure of the primordial Universe, I have very hard time understanding how it is possible to draw a clear picture of what happened in the primordial Universe. Is there a hypothesis that simplifies everything? What am I missing?

What makes you think that the conditions and processes of the early universe are in any way well understood? The only difference is that we can actually (somewhat) look at it in the form of the cosmic microwave background, while the processes in the center of massive bodies are not as easily observed.

@paulina to the extent that they are driven by the Standard Model, conditions of the early universe are very well understood on a theoretical level, see e.g. the literature on big bang nucleosynthesis

The almost-instant of the big bang can be modeled because it is a simpler system than the interior of a supermassive star or a neutron star. In fact the universe as a whole will never again be as simple as it was at that time: a quark-gluon plasma. A star can contain a variety of elements ranging from hydrogen all the way up to iron, segregated by density, plus free electrons, neutrinos, and many wavelengths of radiation- all of which dynamically exchange energy.
All the pertinent details can be found in Weinberg's book The First Three Minutes. It contains the answers to your questions and I highly recommend you read it.

I can understand that for the very primordial Universe. But I was also talking about what comes after the 3 first minutes, and before the CMB. Can you also elaborate on that?

The centre of a neutron star is at densities of $\sim 10^{18}$ kg/m$^3$, temperatures of $10^8$K-$10^{10}$K. The pressures are $\sim 10^{34}$ Pa and the nucleons are separated by $\sim 10^{-15}$ m. The nucleons are relativistically degenerate and governed by poorly understood, many-body short-range nuclear forces.
In contrast, at 1 second into the big bang, whilst temperatures are $10^{11}$ K, the densities are a mere $\sim 10^6$ kg/m$^3$, the nucleon separations are $\sim 10^{-10}$ m, pressures $\sim 10^{21}$ Pa. The nucleons are non-degenerate, essentially a perfect gas and governed by much better understood two-body interactions.
Thus the conditions prior to, and certainly during and after the epoch of nucleosynthesis, are far less extreme than those at the centre of a neutron star.
